# #12 Project Euler: Find the first triangle number with over 500 divisors

Tags: c++

So I tried working out a solution to this problem, but my program is acting very strange.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int triangle_numbers(int n, int meh = 0)
{
    int count = 0;

    //calculate how many divisors there are for meh
    for(int i = 1; i <= meh; i++)
        if(meh%i == 0)
            count++;

    //if the number of divisors for meh is over 500, return meh
    if(count > 500)
        return meh;

    //recursive call to increment n by 1 and set meh to the next triangle number
    triangle_numbers(n+1, meh += n);
}

int main()
{
    int cc = triangle_numbers(1);
    cout << cc << endl;
}
```

If I output `meh` and `count` individually I get accurate results, so I'm not sure why my program is giving me the same number (4246934) even if I do, say, `if(count > 10)`.  I have a feeling it may have to do with my recursive call, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a final `return` statement necessary to complete the recursion (doesn't the compiler warn that `triangle_numbers` does not actually return something in all cases?).

Once the final value of `meh` has been computed, you need to have

```
return triangle_numbers(n+1, meh += n);
```

so that `meh` can be returned all the way back up the call stack and finally to `main`.

The number you are seeing now is probably a value left over on the stack after the recursion does end.

Side note: a classic optimization in this algorithm is to have `i` iterate up to `meh / 2` but no further. Obviously numbers greater than half of `meh` cannot evenly divide it so they can be skipped.

Comment: Thanks.  I just figured that returning meh would be sufficient to end the call.  Although this works now, and I've made the optimization you'd mentioned, I'm experience that it takes a very long time to complete.  Would making the function tail-recursive help with this?

Comment: @BobJohn: The function is already tail-recursive, so no. Improvements can be made by having the function keep state between calls to keep from calculating the same results more than once ([dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)) and at the same time applying more math. The nth triangle number can be directly computed with `n * (n + 1) / 2`, which is pretty useful when we are trying to count its factors...